# How to recover deleted files from mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

In my case, I accidentally deleted a file from my code base, ie, I did a ctrl+delete and cleared trash as well. How to recover the file. In SVN you just do an update on your code base and it will replace the deleted ones. Is it possible in mercurial ?

Comment: I did hg status which showed all the files with an exclamation against the removed ones.
>> hg status
! file1
! file2

The I did hg rever file1. Solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `hg revert MISSING_FILE`